# Where does WAMP server store database files

Tags: windows, windows-xp, database, wamp, mysql

My hard-drive has encountered some problems and I am unable to boot Windows with it.

I am able to view the drive's contents by connecting it to another PC as an external drive.

On the culprit drive I was running a local WAMP server for dev purposes and I'm looking to save the mySQL databases from it.

I can see my wamp directory at `E:\wamp`. Is it possible to start up the server from here so as to use phpmyadmin to perform a mysqldump? If not what are my options to recover the DB-

Comment: Maybe this question would have been better posted on stackoverflow can anybody move it for me?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

On my system, they are in `C:\Program Files (x86)\WampServer\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.53\data`. So in yours they would be in `E:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql-version\data`.

You can start `mysql` locally from `E:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql-version\bin`, where all the executables are. Be aware that the configuration file you want to use is `E:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql-version\my.ini`.

You can also simply copy all the subdirectories to another server. I'm no MySql expert, but that should let the other server use your databases without problem.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like that folder is corrupted for me. I'm getting 'I/O error encountered' messages when trying to view it. It's possible that the folder was a victim of the Hard-drive corruption or maybe even the cause in some way. Nevertheless it looks like your solution is the correct recovery process so I will accept your answer and hopefully it will help others in future. Thanks Jon.

Comment: I replaced full wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24 But it's showing databases, not tables

Comment: After you've changed the location in my.ini, you can start mysqld.exe, (not mysql.exe ). Then you can export your database with phpMyAdmin or HeidiSQL (a desktop application).

Comment: Working perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I needed to re-install Wamp and I recovered my databases by copying the data directory in wamp\bin\mysql\mysql-version\ from a backup, phpMyAdmin picked up the databases and tables.