# Get database without going to localhost/phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

I have a HDD that I installed WAMP5. My computer died so now I have the HDD as a slave. I can get the files but what about the MySQL database? Can I go somewhere in `c:\wamp\` to find the database SQL?

Thank you.

Comment: You should check these answers:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/2093810/970721  
http://stackoverflow.com/a/5515447/970721

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find your databases here: `C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql(version)\data`

For example `...\mysql5.1.36\data`