# InnoDB Tables Not Showing

Tags: mysql, innodb, database-backups

I reinstalled WAMP Server today, the same version I've used to create several databases. All my database data is still present in the original `wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.12/data` files. All the `.frm` and `.ibd` files are present.

What do I need to do to recover these tables?

I've already checked file permissions, modified the `innodb_force_recovery` variable and created a new `mysql-bin.index` file.

Comment: check the mysql directory path in your environment

Comment: This question might better be asked on **dba.stackexchange.com**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where does WAMP server store database files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515403/where-does-wamp-server-store-database-files)

Comment: This isn't a path question. I know where all my files are and so does MySQL. It sees all my databases and it's aware of all my MYISAM tables. It's only the InnoDB tables that MySQL is not reading.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "Not Showing"? Can you see the tables in  SHOW TABLES output? Is the original ibdata1 is still present?